# Grant change password privilege in microsoft access

Tags: sql, ms-access, privileges, sql-grant

I have a database built in Microsoft Access and have two users:

- DBAdmin
- User

DBAdmin is the administrator and has all privileges. User has only the ability to modify entries in all tables and change his/her password.

How would I be able to grant the privilege to change his/her password using SQL? I looked on the Internet, and I found about system privileges but none was helpful.

Comment: You may wish to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139961(v=office.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to [because users are allowed to change their own passwords in the Jet security model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx).

Comment: you have no idea how much I've been looking for this link? thanks mate.